# on/in/at the beginning stage of something

Tags: prepositions, in-on-at

Please help me figure out which preposition is correct and give me a reason.

> In China, students always use the book to learn alphabets ***in/at/on*** the beginning stage of learning English.

Comment: Why would Chinese students need a whole *book* from which to learn the (effectively arbitrary) sequence of 26 symbols? In most fonts, the complete list would be less than a single *line* of text, even if you included both upper and lower case, *and* spaces between each symbol.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thank you for answering. How do you write a sentence expressing this?

Comment: *In China, students always use **a** book to learn **the alphabet** in the **first** stage(s) of learning English.* It still seems like a rather odd thing to say anyway, but I'm not sure exactly what you want to convey. Personally, I don't really see how *"using a book"* comes into it. A more meaningful and "natural" statement might be something like *Chinese students always learn the alphabet **as** the first stage **in** learning English.*

Comment: @FumbleFingers "the book" would be acceptable - the assumption being that which book it is was already specified in a prior sentence.

Comment: Yes – 'in the first stages', but 'as the first stage'.

Comment: Alexander: In that case I feel like "this" would probably be more likely. "Today I'd like to talk to you about The Magic Book of the English Alphabet. In China, students always use *this* book..." (Not saying there's no scenario where *the* would work, just that *this* seems more likely to apply.) @FumbleFingers All I can think is that it's one of those short little reading books where each page has 1 alphabet letter and a few words beginning with that letter?

Comment: @WendiKidd: My only experience of the first stages of learning a language are English (which I don't remember! :) and French (which uses the same alphabet). I don't have any actual *knowledge*  of how Chinese students start learning English, but it would seem likely to me they'd start by "rote learning" the collation sequence, written forms, and "name/standard sound" of the 26 symbols. Maybe they do use the equivalent of an Anglophone "child's alphabet" book, but that seems unlikely to me (at that stage, what's the point in being told that ***X** is for **Xylophone***, for example?).

Answer (score 2):

"In" or "at" are both acceptable to specify a stage or point in time. "On" is less used for that purposes, and tends to be more informal. Someone might say "We're on learning the alphabet in Chinese class", but it would be less likely to be written in a more formal sentence, like the one you've given as an example.

Incidentally, alphabet is singular when you are talking about only one set of letters (the "English alphabet"; but "the Greek and Tamil alphabets").

Answer (score 0):

Strictly answering your question and making the sentence correct. There is only one alphabet in question—the English alphabet. This is done "in" the beginning stage since a stage is a period of time. You do the action while you are "in" the stage.

> In China, students always use the book to learn the alphabet in the beginning stage of learning English.

English learners from a Chinese background will often use too many commas near the beginning of sentences. This sentence could be made more clear by flipping the order of the words:

> Students in China always use the book to learn the alphabet in the beginning stage of learning English.

Or to change the words some:

> Chinese students begin to learn English by studying the alphabet in the book.